# Image left to TextView, Textview should be in center

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to take a textview within Tablelayout with a image icon left to TextView. The TableLayout have width has fill_parent, so that whole area is clickable.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/down_arrow"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</TableLayout>
```

I tried to bring the Textview with image to center, but not able to do that.
Kindly help me to achieve the same.

Thanks
Vikash

[image: This is the output i am getting, I need textview and Image in center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<TableLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_launcher_0"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In that case Image is still there in the previous position.

Comment: you want image should also be in center?

Comment: The TextView should be in center and Icon just left to that.

Comment: @VikashKumar now check the updated code. hope will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have to use TableLayout only. It is required for some other purpose.